# Could I add GPT BIOS Boot Partition after Debian installation?

Tags: debian, grub2, gpt

I recently installed Debian Wheezy on a server with 24TB of storage (RAID 6). When I partitioned the big volume I selected Manual option and created the partition scheme.

When I was partitioning, I observed that Debian automatically created two small partitions of 1MiB (one at beginning and another at end of disk). I inmediately remembered that this space was probably being allocated for [GPT BIOS Boot Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition) so I didn't worry about it and I left them there.

However, when I installed a new kernel through Debian updates and GRUB was reinstalled I received the next error message:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: This GPT partition label has no BIOS Boot
Partition; embedding won't be possible!

/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only
be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists
are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.

Installation finished. No error reported.
```

This message is fairly clear. However, despite GRUB was correctly installed and this server is booting fine, I would like to avoid this problem.

If I execute `parted` I can see that this space is being identified as free so my question is: Could I use parted to create a new partition in this free space (at beginning or end of disk) and set it as GPT BIOS Boot Partition (`set [num] bios_grub on`)? Could it be risky to do it now (after installation)?

Comment: Try and see? It should work fine.